# How to recover completely darkened screen on Moto G (Lollipop) due to setting brightness to zero?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, screen-brightness

I have Moto G on Lollipop, and I mistakenly set the brightness bar to zero. Now, the screen is completely darkened and I'm not able to see anything.

How to set back the brightness to usable mode without hitting factory reset?

Comment: Are you sure you set it this way?  I've never known a phone to go completely black if the bar is set to 0, usually it's just very dim.

Comment: yes i slided the brighness bar it went full dim. I have the lock screen, is it making it more darker? if i reboot the phone i can see the bootup animation and when it completes it goes dark. I can hear my ringtone if I get call.

Comment: You didn't told us the whole story. Do you have stock ROM or custom ROM? How did you enable the possibility to achieve brightness level to 1 instead of 10?

Comment: I had the same problem. For the record: I shone something bright (e.g. a flashlight) on the light sensor, and then I saw the screen and could increase the brightness.

Answer (score 8):

Had same problem.  I believe the adaptive brightness auto adjust it to zero light.
I use another phone flash light and direct it on the the front camera and light sensor. Unlocking with power button awaken my screen with adjusted brightness.. 
Hope this will help...

Comment: You can go to a bright room or outside too. Angle the screen towards the light source and try to unlock the phone -- the screen will adjust. It may take a few tries. Then go to Settings -> Display and turn off the adaptive brightness. Pick a brightness level you like and then phone will be back to normal.

Comment: worked like magic!!!

Comment: bless you rudhra, we already wanted to return the phone :)

Answer (score 2):

Using ADB Tool, you can adjust the device brightness, by following command

> adb shell settings put system screen_brightness 200

In order to get more info about what ADB is and other details refer the [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) tag-wiki.

To Run below command, you need following:

1. Computer/Laptop with  with ADB Installed.
2. Computer/Laptop Should recognize device when connected via USB. Install necessary device driver software to ensure device is detected by system.
3. Connect device to Computer/Laptop using USB.
4. Start command line program (like cmd in Windows or bash shell in Linux) and go to location where "adb" executable is placed, and run above mentioned command.

Comment: I am getting adb installed will update once i try it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i am getting /system/bin/sh: settings: not found

Comment: Looks like i have not enabled usb debugging on my phone :(. The reponse i got was from emulator running on my windows.

Comment: You need to test this on device only!! you need to first make sure that your PC/ADB Detects your device via USB.

Comment: @AADTechnical maybe you could [edit] your answer and include a short hint on the requirements? Not everyone is familiar with what ADB is. You could link to the [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for details (which also includes hints on its installation for "newcomers"). Thanks!

Comment: Not working with android naugat

Answer (score 2):

Try to increase brightness in the same dark condition. Lock the phone using power button. Swipe up. Swipe down twice. Then try to move your finger left to right on the top 30% of your screen. Eventually you will be able to get your screen back. Do it patiently. It works. And be careful till this bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to hard reset my phone to fix this problem.