# Why can't I adjust the brightness and the sleep time on my KitKat device?

Tags: settings, screen-brightness, sleep

Whenever I go to settings and to display, the brightness and the sleep buttons are faded out and I can't click them. I tried rebooting my phone and a factory reset but nothing works. I don't know what to do as I can't adjust my phone brightness or the sleep time. I'm using an Alcatel Pixi 3 (4.5) and  it's running on KitKat 4.4.

Comment: It's a weird problem. For now, you can use adb commands to change screen brightness, check this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/97388/27149)

Answer (score 1):

Go to sitting then barrery manager and turn off that feature you should be able to adjust your brightness and time out features then it's that simple

Comment: Same solution is valid on Android 7